# A cheap way to convert between USDT and USDC

Tags: exchanges

Any decentralized cheaper way to convert usdt and USDC? I heard that usdt and usdt also freeze the assets? Any reliable usd service that can not freeze assets?

Comment: USDT and USDC are both _centralised_ stablecoins under the control of Tether and Circle respectively. If you don't want the risk of having your assets frozen, use a decentralised stablecoin instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Curve](https://curve.fi) is the leading stablecoin-to-stablecoin exchange, touting their very low slippage approach.

Answer (score 0):

It would be cheaper to exchange these tokens on an L2 or an alternative L1 (not ETH, due to relatively high fees). But then you would have to bridge the assets over to the L2 or alternate L1 and bridge the resulting tokens back if you wanted to use them on ETH.

If you want to keep them on Ethereum, the best option is Curve which is designed for stable exchange (you won't get nearly as good a rate on something like Uniswap, eg). You can also use Curve on L2s and non-ETH L1s.